# I'm trying to find what the 197 penal code was in the 1930's

Tags: california, legal-history

For a project on the book ''Of Mice and Of Men'', I have to prove that George is innocent of the murder of Lennie. My goal is to say that George didn't commit murder, but that it was a justified homicide. I'm planning to use the 4 point underneath a justified homicide : ''When necessarily committed in attempting, by lawful ways and means, to apprehend any person for any felony committed, or in lawfully suppressing any riot, or in lawfully keeping and preserving the peace''. So, I'll say how George is technically protecting future victims of George.

So I need to find what the Californian 197 Penal Code which is on justified homicide was in 1930's around. Does someone know where I could find it?

Comment: a perfect case of "law in history"

Comment: Nice argument- it won’t fly, however. Why don’t you ask a question about why this defense won’t work.

Comment: Why wouldn't it fly? Do you mean that they could say that George wasn't lawfully suppressing a riot or something like that? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @DaleM, probaly should have tagged you. If you don't have the time to answer, it's fine.

Comment: @Caden yes, you should have tagged me. But I won’t answer your comment - I encourage you to write a question setting out your defence and asking if it will work.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I think that's a really cool project!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a pdf of the original [Penal Code of California](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc2.ark:/13960/t9x067b09&view=1up&seq=116&q1=197): enacted in 1872 and as amended up to and including 1905. I cannot find any further amendments made before the publication of Of Mice and Men in 1937 (#197 is on page 116)...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is a lot of help!

Comment: @Caden. You're welcome

Comment: FYI there was a 1931 amendment which substituted “mutual combat” for “mortal combat” in subd 3; compare the original to the current. They also substituted “any” for “either” in the introductory clause in 1963.